# Need advice what is the way for starting developing iOS apps on windows

Tags: ios, windows

I need to develop iOS apps on windows with coding(using any language), so please tell me how can i start ,what tools needed, what is the requirements for doing this job and what is the restrictions&problems exist in this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install any virtual machine in your windows .Then you can install mac os . After that you can install xcode, an IDE for developing iOS apps.

Now you are ready to code using xcode, but you need to learn objective-c, only language available to build iOS app(but now there is new language introduced known as swift programming language). But I recommend start by learning objective-c.

Comment: please which type of mac os and its version to install, and where can i download it?

Comment: When I was using the windowns 1 year earlier ,I did download of mountain lion os-x, you will find it here:  http://en.softonic.com/s/os-x-10.8-mountain-lion-free-download:mac , and also you can easily find the latest version of xcode in the internet. But I am unknown about the latest OS Yosemite and latest X-code 6, but still you can install xcode 5.1 to mountain os x and run it on windows.

Comment: what about OS X 10.9 Mavericks? and which better Mavericks or mountain lion?

Comment: I'm afraid,I've no experience of mavericks in vmware.

Comment: Never Mind thanks for your help and your frankness, but the link led me to mac app store?? how can i download it?

Answer (score 1):

iOS development is possible in OS X ONLY, there's no way to do it on Windows (using OS X virtual machine on Windows is technically not legal, but possible).

Even if you create app in PhoneGap/Cordova/Worklight (HTML+CSS+JS), you still need OS X's Xcode to compile it.

Comment: why not legal?are there disadvantages related to using OS X virtual machine on windows?

Comment: Disadvantages are "only" legal related. The Apple software license does not allow Mac OS X to be used on hardware that is not "Apple-branded", which, of course, includes all Windows PCs.

Comment: And because you need Apple ID to download Xcode from Mac App Store, I would hesitate to do it from a non-legit OS X.

Comment: Please I downloaded Xcode5.1.1 from apple site,how can I download OS X Mavericks?

Comment: Sorry, I use OS X on company Mac (on which you can download OS X right from Mac App Store), no experience of doing it on a PC. And I assume it has to be somehow modified to run on non-Apple HW.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi XE6 is a quite smart solution for creating apps for iOS/Andriod/WP/Windows.

**Pro:**

- Easy to learn. I wrote my first iOS game for kids with only 2 day work.
- Quick to market. You can write code once and deploy to all platforms.

**Con:**

- As a commercial product, its license fee is remarkable. Upgrade costs money as well.
- You still need a Mac to compile code and to deploy.

Comment: Can I use any language instead of Delphi in XE6 or not?

Comment: @MohammedMostafa Sure. Delphi is one solution among them. The best way is to use XCode to create native iOS applications.

Comment: Sorry, use XCode in Delphi XE6?

Comment: @MohammedMostafa Delphi uses XCode's as a tool to build and deploy project. As I mentioned, this is one of those solutions out there. You can also write objective-c code with XCode only. It depends on your coding background and preference. For me, I use Delphi for more than 10 years, so Delphi will be easier for me rather than learning another language from the scratch.

Comment: Ok,many thanks for these information

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it is not worth it. I have tried a virtual machine on Windows, but it was slow and painful. Get a second hand mac and start learning. I suggest learning the new Swift language, you will be ahead of competition.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a Windows PC or laptop with any Intel Core "i"-series CPU (go to ark.intel.com and ensure your CPU has "Yes" in the fields `Intel® VT-x with Extended Page Tables (EPT)` and `Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x)`), and at least 6-8 GB RAM.

Install VMWare workstation, download e.g. "OS X Mavericks 10.9.1 Pre-Installed VMware Image", ensure the virtual machine has 4GB RAM and 2 cores, run the OSX, install xCode, go on with the development. Optionally, [disable the paging](http://soonts.livejournal.com/352030.html).

I've been using VMware for a year for iOS development. Thanks to my fast SSD, it works faster then most Apple machines I saw.

Comment: Thanks for these information i will try and see, please give me locations for these tools to download and if there any help link for installing and developing,thanks.

Comment: I can’t do that.

Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service paragraph 3 says “Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party”.

Giving you any links to thepiratebay.se would definitely violate copyright of VmWare Inc. and Apple Inc.